# Get Variable string from Class where Class name matches with CheckedListBox item name

Tags: c#, winforms

I have few classes in **MyApp** project under the folder "**SQLQueries**" as shown below.  Each class has SQL query string constant variable named "**QUERY**".

```
namespace MyApp.SQLQueries
{
    public class Product
    {
        private const string QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT";
    }
}

namespace MyApp.SQLQueries
{
    public class Order
    {
        private const string QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM ORDER";
    }
}

namespace MyApp.SQLQueries
{
    public class Customer
    {
        private const string QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";
    }
}
```

On my **WinForm** I've below code where I've CheckedListBox with collection of items with names "**Product**", "**Order**" and "**Customer**" which matches with the class names shown above.  I want that when I click on button then I should be able to retrieve query string from the class variable "**QUERY**" (as shown above) where class name matches with checkedListBox1 item name?  Is it anyway possible to do?

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(dbCnxStr))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    string sql = item.ToString(); // need to retrieve QUERY variable string from the class which matches with checkedListBox1 item name
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (sqlRd.HasRows)
                            {
                                dt.Load(sqlRd);
                            }

                            sqlRd.Close();
                        }

                        sqlCmd.Dispose();
                    } 
                }

                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make that happen but you could design it better. How about a Dictionary with the name as key and sql query as value?

Comment: Could you please give me code example that how to achieve this in Dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should refactor to be a Dictionary (kami) or a List...

Anyway, if you do not consider it, you must firt instatiate the class by name and then use the property you need.

```
var type = Type.GetType("sql");
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
myObject.QUERY;
```

NOTE: untested code.

EDIT: Dictionary solution:

```
            Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            d.Add("Product", "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT");
            d.Add("Order", "SELECT * FROM ORDER");
            d.Add("Customer", "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");

            var x = d.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "Order")
                        .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            if(x.Key != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{x.Value}"); //this should return "SELECT * FROM ORDER"
            }
```

Comment: Could you please give me code example that how to achieve this in Dictionary or list?

Comment: Edited my previous answer.